# Why does the code not add 3hrs to the time?

Tags: c#, datetime

```
    Literal four = new Literal();
    string timeanddate;
    timeanddate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(timeanddate);
    dt.AddHours(3);
    four.Text = "3hr added and this gives>>  " + dt.ToString();
    form1.Controls.Add(four);
```

It should add 3 to hrs but does not, it's like the line addhours does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `DateTime` type is immutable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828917/most-awkward-misleading-method-in-the-net-api/2828960#2828960)

Luckily, the solution is quite simple:

```
dt = dt.AddHours(3);
```